# Errors configuring mysql 7 after upgrade to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, mysql

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and now can not get MySQL 5.7 to work. I tried:

```
sudo apt purge mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-common mysql-client mysql-
```

client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common dbconfig-mysql

to make sure i removed everything. Then did:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

This is what I now get:

```
Instellen van mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Instellen van mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Instellen van mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf wordt gebruikt om in de   automatische modus in /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) te voorzien.
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin'*F352881E3CD02CC99A548F7D72920636157BEEBF' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
subproces post-installation script geïnstalleerd gaf een foutwaarde 1 terug
Instellen van mysql-client (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van mysql-server:
mysql-server is afhankelijk van mysql-server-5.7; maar:
Pakket mysql-server-5.7 is nog niet geconfigureerd.

dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket mysql-server (--configure):
vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Er is geen apport-verslag weggeschreven omdat de foutmelding aangeeft dat de fout het gevolg is van een eerdere mislukking.
                                                                             Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor systemd (229-4ubuntu5) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That error number suggests that you have something in your 'mysql' database (the one it uses for settings) that is incompatible with this version of mysql.

The plugin could not be loaded to handle that bit of data and that is preventing mysql from loading.

I'm guessing its a maria db thing that is not supported in mysql.

One way round this would be to reinstall mariadb and then dump the data to sql text, delete the db's , retry the switch to mysql with no data and then add the data manually afterwards. This should give you better visibility of the errors and show you where its stopping, you can then see the data and decide if and how you want to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your remark! Not sure how I would deal with this though :-)

Comment: Do and apt-get install of the packages you purged , then use mysqldump

Comment: when you have the dump you can then try importing into a new install of maria db one db at time.  The dump file is a big text file that is human readble, if you open it with a text editor you can split it in to individual databases and save them as separate files.
  Missing  out the 'mysql' database will mean the access permissions are not migrated , you could then recreate them in a form that mariadb likes to restore the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the support amias! I have done as you suggested but I still run into some issues :-) I actually do need a local PHP5.6 and a MySQL 5.6 or earlier so I am going to install 15.10 again.